# Make a .json-file more flexible with Variables for automation deploy

Tags: powershell, azure

I've got a PowerShell-Script to create a VM from an Image in Azure and in this Script I deposited a `.json` (Parameter for VM, etc.). But if I want to create more than one VM the Names of the VM, Vnet, etc. cannot be the same for every execution (have to be in the same Resource Group).

So my Question: How can I insert Variables in the .json File to change the Name of the VM, etc. for every execution? Perhaps I have to rethink?

[image: PowerShell-Script]

Comment: Please put your code in the question; not in a picture!

Comment: @OP this is still an image and not the actual code text. Also be aware that your full name (username) is available in the image. You may wish to redact this

Answer (score 2):

A very basic approach could be something like this:

```
# Grab the file contents
$contents = Get-Content -Path $templateFile

# Update some tokens in the file contents
$contents = $contents.replace("original value", "new value")

# Push the updated contents to a new file
Set-Content -Path $updatedFile -Value $contents
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But if I unsterstand it correctly I would create a new file and have to deposite it in the next script again, isn't it?

Comment: @Eiffelsturm you know in your code where you specify `-TemplateFile $templateFile`... just swap the variable around! Give it a _try_.

Comment: Yeah thank you, I think that's what I wanted. It seems to be working and I'll write if ti works for me soon. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have a value that changes with every deployment, you could also consider using the **-TemplateParameterObject** parameter with the New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet. That way, you can generate the values in your powershell script without having to output them to json file first.

For more details, have a look at the [cmdlet specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-5.5.0)